# Which of these are subgroups of $S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question asks: Which of the following are groups of permutations of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, that is, which of them are subgroups of $S_5$?

$ \text{(i)} \{(12345), (124)(35)\} \\ \text{(ii)}\{id, (12345), (13524), (14253),(15432)\} \\ \text{(iii)}\{id, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\} \\ \text{(iv)}\{id, (12)(345), (135)(24), (15324),(12)(45),(134)(25),(143)(25)\}
$

So far I have narrowed it down by eliminating (i) and (iv). My reasons for this are that (i) does not have an identity element, so it cannot possibly be a group, and (iv) has order 7 which is not a divisor of 120 (the order of $S_5$).

Now I know that I can show that these two finite sets are subgroups if they satisfy the first axiom of subgroups, closure. But I'm not quite sure how I can show this.

Comment: Hint: (ii) is a cyclic subgroup of order 5.  Pick any non-identity element and show the others are powers of it.  (iii) is easy to check for closure because of symmetry.  Each element is order 2, and any two nonidentity elements should give the third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

Check to confirm that $ii$ is cyclic, generated by any *one* of it's elements.

For $iii$, check that the order of every element other than the identity is of order $2$, and ensure that every element is the product of two other elements in the set, just as is the Klein $4$-group, hence forms a group. Note also that if any set of four elements with identity is a group, it is either cyclic, or isomorphic to the Klein 4-group. If a four-element candidate-group is not isomorphic to one of these groups, it fails to be a subgroup, indeed, it fails to be a group.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

I -- What are the powers of $\;(12345)\;$ ?

II -- The example in (iii) is a (normal, by the way) subgroup of $\;A_4\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

The second is a subgroup isomorphic to $C_5$ and the third is a subgroup isomorphic to the Klein $4$-group. For questions on subgroups of $S_5$ see [*here*](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group%3aS5).